# HHVM - Rewrite rules for clean URLS

Tags: redirect, drupal-7, hhvm

I have links like this - `http://example.com/index.php?q=about` and I want to make them look like this - `http://example.com/about`

Currently I am using the Rewrite Rules

```
VirtualHost {
  * {
    Pattern = .*
    RewriteRules {
      dirindex {
        pattern = (.*)/$
        to = index.php/$1
        qsa = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I visit http://example.com/about I am getting a `404 File Not Found`

I am doing this for Drupal. Guidelines for clean urls : https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls

Comment: I have written an answer to this issue (which I have manually tested myself, and works). If it solves your issue, please select it as the answer, and if not, please explain your issue further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be resolved using the VirtualHost, but the server module of HHVM is depreciated now, and you are encouraged to use fastcgi over apache/nginx. I will put an answer for VirtualHost, but if needed, can update with an nginx alternative.

First, make sure that your SourceRoot is correct:

```
Server {
  Port = 9000
  SourceRoot = /home/myuser/www
  DefaultDocument = index.php
}
```

Now, for the rule, this should potentially work:

```
VirtualHost {
  * {
    Pattern = .*
    RewriteRules {
      * {
        pattern = (.*)$
        to = index.php/$1
        qsa = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want the query to work exactly as you are intending it to, replace the inner pattern with this:

```
* {
pattern = /(.*)
to = index.php?q=$1
qsa = true
}
```

I have tested these both, and they work well. If you are still facing an issue, the issue may be potentially with your setup. Make sure you enable [Error and Access logging](https://gist.github.com/sinaa/9148576) .